# Which effect leads to the same electrical current in a closed circuit consisting of different resistive materials?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electrical-resistance

Suppose you connect two wires with different resistances to form a single wire. When you apply a voltage, a current will flow. Do the electrons in the wire with smaller resistance move with a higher drift velocity compared to the wire with higher resistance? Obviously, both carry the same current, but this could be explained by having different electron densities in each wire.
The alternative explanation would be that electrons in the wire with smaller resistance experience a smaller voltage gradient, leading to a smaller acceleration, but at the same time, they have less collisions with the atoms of the wire material, allowing them to gain a higher velocity. The opposite would be true for electrons in the wire with higher resistance, leading to the same drift velocity in both wire materials.

Comment: No, this is a delicate balancing act. It does not matter what the mobility, the drift velocity, the density of charge carriers, and so forth, are, because in the end the system would have enough time to reach steady state of constant current flow. It is the conservation of charge that forces the entire circuit to balance out the voltage drop each component gets.

Comment: Does 'balancing act' mean a mix of both answers I gave describes the steady state current?

Comment: Neither. You are assuming too much